# Como incrementar número à uma variável em JS?

Tags: javascript

Eu quero saber como incrementar um número à uma variável em JS toda vez que ela passar pelo loop while. Por exemplo:

```
var num2 = 1;

while(num2 < num){
    new google.maps.Marker({
        position: posicao(incrementar valor de num2 aqui),
        title: nome(incrementar valor de num2 aqui),
        map: map
    });

    num2++;
}
```

Comment: Mas você já está fazendo isso...

Comment: Não, cara. Quero que o valor de num2 seja incrementado às variáveis posicao e nome. Tipo, elas vão começar como: posicao1 e nome1, depois, posicao2 e nome2, e daí por diante.

Comment: Mas `position` e `title` são `strings` ? Pode dar exemplos de valores que elas tenham ?

Comment: Pessoal, resolver esse problema me ajudaria também: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/309026/como-chamar-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-js-via-php. Já que só estou tentando desta forma usada neste post porque não consegui da maneira do post do link

Comment: Isac, ambas são variáveis que estão recebendo valores do BD, como por exemplo: position: -9.838877963370699
-39.485223973571806 e nome: marcador de teste

Comment: O uso do `eval()` não é muito recomendado, mas nesses casos não vejo problema: `position: eval('posicao'+num2),`

Comment: Sugiro tornar a pergunta o mais clara possivel, para evitar que quem responda tenha que editar varias vezes por não ter acertado exatamente no que você pretende. Coloque um exemplo de `position` e `title` antes e depois de ser "aumentado".

Comment: Pessoal, com o link(https://jsfiddle.net/qc0g5j8f/) que o @dvd postou solucionou o problema já. Obrigado a todos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode fazer desta forma, criando 2 variáveis concatenando à variável:

```
var num2 = 1;

while(num2 < num){

   var posicao = "posicao"+num2;
   var nome = "nome"+num2;

    new google.maps.Marker({
        position: posicao,
        title: nome,
        map: map
    });

    num2++;
}
```

Comment: Tipo assim, deu certo, mas só na parte da concatenação. Tipo assim, o que estou fazendo é o seguinte: Leio os dados do BD, passo eles pelo echo via variáveis tipo posicao1, nome1, posicao2, nome2. Só que na hora de ler os dados no JS para adicionar os marcadores no mapa, eu teria que ir incrementando um número às variáveis posicao e nome. No seu exemplo está ficando correto a implementação do número à variável, mas não está lendo o marcador, por exemplo

Comment: Assim como?....

Comment: Já que, no caso, posicao1, nome1, posicao2, nome2 e assim por diante são variáveis que preciso captura-las

Comment: É bem confuso já que estou utilizando várias linguagens ao mesmo tempo, mas ele já está funcionando normalmente, tanto que se fizer apenas um if pedindo para ele apenas aquela posição e nome, tipo, posicao3 e nome3, ele irá ler exatamente os dados pedidos. Mas como não sei quantos marcadores terão preciso de um loop

Comment: Faz o teste usando eval() como coloquei lá nos comentários.

Comment: Desta forma: https://jsfiddle.net/qc0g5j8f/3/

Comment: Exato! Cara, muito obrigado, tu me poupou muita dor de cabeça.